# Is it possible for other users on a network to track if anyone has been going around through my stuff?

Tags: file-sharing

The title pretty much says it all, but some of my folders have change there content and i am wondering if anyone has somehow Changed them, this is happening at work,i'm sure because at home i leave my laptop closed up in a safe. I know that's a but cautious but its like a $5000 alien-ware.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Folders are on network, you may ask your network Administrator to find out which User wrote into the file at Last.

If the Folders are on your laptop, you can still try to find out the User accessed the file at Last. If it is your Login, someone must have cracked your password.

Comment: i see,but i am the Administrator of my network....